400 Bad Request: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'
tengo el siguiente problema, estoy montando una aplicacion en vue y tengo un componente que desde el cual debo hacer subidas de archivos a a mi bucket de gcp, pero a la hora de enviar la petición de subida desde mi front al back, me da el error del titulo
este es mi front:
<template>
  <div class="upload-container">
    <h4>Subida de Ficheros</h4>
    <b-form-file v-model="file" class="mt-3" plain></b-form-file>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="uploadFile">Upload File</button>
    <p v-if="errorMessage" class="error">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
    <p v-if="successMessage" class="success">{{ successMessage }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { sp } from '@/utils/constants'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      file: null,
      errorMessage: null,
      successMessage: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async uploadFile () {
      if (!this.file) {
        this.errorMessage = 'Please select a file to upload.'
        return
      }
      this.errorMessage = null
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('file', this.file)
      try {
        const response = await fetch(sp + 'upload_file', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
        })
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Error: ${response.statusText}`)
        }
        const result = await response.json()
        this.successMessage = 'File uploaded successfully'
        console.log('Response from server:', result)
      } catch (error) {
        this.errorMessage = `Error uploading file: ${error.message}`
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
.error {
  color: red;
}
.success {
  color: green;
}
</style>

y este es mi back, montado en python del cual parece que aun no se ejecuta nada:
@surveys_bp.route('/upload_file', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    try:
        logging.info('Handling upload file request')
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            logging.error('No file part in the request')
            return jsonify({'message': 'No file part in the request'}), 400
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            logging.error('No selected file')
            return jsonify({'message': 'No selected file'}), 400
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        logging.info(f'File received: {filename}')
        # Intentar subir el archivo a GCP
        try:
            upload_to_gcp(file, filename)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Error uploading file to GCP', exc_info=True)
            return jsonify({'message': f'Error uploading file to GCP: {str(e)}'}), 500
        logging.info('File uploaded successfully')
        return jsonify({'message': 'File uploaded successfully'}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error handling upload file request', exc_info=True)
        return jsonify({'message': str(e)}), 500


def upload_to_gcp(file, filename):
    """Sube un archivo a Google Cloud Storage."""
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket('files_pending_processing')
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)
    file_content = file.read()
    blob.upload_from_string(file_content, content_type=file.mimetype)
    logging.info(f'File {filename} uploaded to GCP bucket.')

la llamada no llega a entrar nunca en el proceso del back, si no que siempre vuelca el error comentado en el titulo, he probado enviando la peticion  con axios y ahora con         fetch y nada, siempre indica el mismo mensaje y tambien he incluido muchas veces en el headers el tipo de content/type y nada.

Probaste usando  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, en fetch?

si y nada sigue indicando lo mismo
